# a helloworld in jsf 2 not work?

Tags: eclipse, jsf-2

i working with my first jsf hello world but this is not working...
i use jboss application server 6 + Jbosstools eclipse plugin
my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>PesianJ</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml</param-value>
   </context-param>

   <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
   </context-param>


  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

my page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"> 
<head>
<title>hello world</title>
</head>

<h:body>

<h:form>

<table>

<tr>
<td>Name:</td>
<td>
<h:inputText label="first name" id="fname" value="#{userBean.firstName}" required="true"/>
<h:message for="fname"/>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Family:</td>
<td>
<h:inputText label="last name" id="lname" value="#{userBean.lastName}" required="true"/>
<h:message for="lname"/>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Sex:</td>
<td>
<h:selectOneRadio label="sex" id="sex" value="userBean.sex" required="true">
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Male" itemValue="male"/>
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Female" itemValue="female"/>
</h:selectOneRadio>
<h:message for="sex"/>

<h:inputText id="date" label="Date Of Birthday" value="#{userbean.date}" >
<f:convertDateTime pattern="MM-dd-yy"/>
(mm-dd-yy)
<h:message for="date"/>
</td>
</tr>

</table>
<h:commandButton value="register" action="confirm" />
</h:form>

</h:body>

</html>
```

and exception i give is :

```
07:26:45,939 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/PesianJ].[Faces Servlet]] Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.notifyAfter(RestoreViewPhase.java:288) [:2.0.3-]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:110) [:2.0.3-]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:114) [:2.0.3-]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:308) [:2.0.3-]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:324) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:181) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.event(CatalinaContext.java:285) [:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.invoke(CatalinaContext.java:261) [:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:88) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:100) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.request.ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.invoke(ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.java:53) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:654) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:951) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_26]
```

EDit:
my face-config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">


</faces-config>
```

itry http://localhost:8080/app/register.jsf
i give excption in browser and eclipse stacktrace console.
ithink other information is not neccesary..please help me!
thanks alot

Comment: You tagged MyFaces, but the stacktrace shows that you're using Mojarra. What JSF implementation are you now using? Do you have any JSF libs in your webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib`? Do you realize that JBoss ships with its own JSF libraries? It might have collided with the ones which you've put in your webapp without setting the necessary JBoss-specific context param in `web.xml` which should tell it to use the WAR-bundled JSF impl.

Comment: some one told me that i shouldn't add them in lib folder when i use jboss 6 so i sid'nt add anything.it is not true?

Comment: Okay. Why did you tag MyFaces then? Do you know what MyFaces is?

Comment: i am following a tutorial .now i don't no more thing about them.this is first tutorial on "jsf complete refrence"book.if i delete that every thing will be ok?

Comment: Okay, I'll remove MyFaces tag as you don't seem to be using MyFaces at all. Back to the problem, the stacktrace indicates that the `UIViewRoot` is `null` at that point which in turn indicates that the view mapping is completely broken. Can you please show what URL you were using in the browser to invoke the page? Can you please show the JSF error message you're seeing in the browser window? Is it a `FileNotFoundException`? Can you please show the `faces-config.xml` file -if any? Use *edit* link to update your question.

Comment: i add new edition dear..

Comment: Everything looks fine as far. Do you have any JAR files in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder of the project? Can you list them? Perhaps one of them is colliding. In order to run this project on JBoss AS, actually no one JAR file is required at all in `/WEB-INF/lib`.

Comment: jstl and standard and 5 common-* file that all of them put by eclipse ide by default..another thing is that wen i try adress with .xhtml it works but when i try by .jsf problem start!

Comment: JBoss already ships with JSTL. Remove the JSTL and standard JAR files and retry. As to using `*.xhtml` suffix, do you see the input field being rendered? Well, then perhaps your JBoss version has that mapping builtin. You should remove the mapping from your `web.xml` or change it from `*.jsf` to `*.xhtml`.

Comment: by deleting them now all of things are prefect..thanks alot.i am not a member too mark your comment as great but i realy thank you for your great helps..people like you are angel!

Comment: I'll repost it as an answer so that you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the answer on my comment what your `/WEB-INf/lib` contains:

> *jstl and standard and 5 common- file that all of them put by eclipse ide by default..*

JBoss already ships with JSTL. It might have collided with those files. Remove the JSTL and standard JAR files and retry.